# Where's the upvote for primary

Tags: bug, status-completed, election-2012

Where are the upvote buttons for primary ? Is this a bug or do we need to wait ?

Comment: @KyleBrandt The beatings will continue until code quality improves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fix is being deployed.  There was a missing encoding while switching to razor - my bad.

Comment: Must...resist...urge...to...make....razor...death...of...1000...encodings...joke.... DAMNIT!